# Is $\ln|z|$ harmonic in the punctured disk

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions, multivalued-functions

1.
how can i show that $\ln|z|$ is harmonic in punctured disk ?

2. also $\ln|z|$ has no harmonic conjugate in $\Bbb  C\setminus\{0 \}$ but has in $\Bbb C\setminus[0, \infty)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second part of (2) should be clear, since $\Bbb C\setminus[0,\infty)$ is simply connected. **Hint** for the first part:

> > **Lemma 1** If $f$ is holomorphic in an open set $V$ then $\int_\gamma f'(z)\,dz=0$ for any smooth closed curve $\gamma$ in $V$.
> >
> > **Lemma 2.** If $f=u+iv$ is holomorphic in some open set, where $u(z)=\ln|z|$, then $f'(z)=1/z$.

Hint for Lemma 2: The Cauchy-Riemann equations show that $$f=\frac12(u_x-iu_y).$$(You can simplfy the calculation of $u_x$ and $u_y$ by writing $u(z)=\frac12\ln(x^2+y^2)$.)

Comment: thankyou i got it

Answer (score 0):

1. $z \mapsto \ln |z|$ is locally the real part of a determination of the complex logarithm, so it is locally harmonic, therefore harmonic on the whole punctured disc.